# I can save the image, but it's black

Tags: php, jquery, image-processing, crop, image-uploading

I am using a nice tool called [cropit](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/) and built a little application: [You can check it out here](http://code.reloado.com/ejiyov3)

Now I tried to save the image instead of opening it in a new windows. I used this:

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.export').click(function() {
    var imageData = $('#image-cropper').cropit('export');
    $.post('upload.php', { imageData: imageData }, function() {
      alert("success");
    })
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$imageData = $_POST['imageData'];
$decoded = urldecode($imageData);
$exp = explode(',', $decoded);
$base64 = array_pop($exp);
$data = base64_decode($base64);
$file = 'data.png';
file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

In result I get a PNG file in my directory, which does not get an error when I open (I can zoom and do stuff), but it is blank. How do I make the image appear in the file?

Comment: `urldecode` is totally unnecessary when using POST.

Comment: now it worked! Thanks!